# Русский как иностранный

Tags: discussion

Уважаемые коллеги!

В моём университете поступило предложение самоорганизоваться для изучения русского языка как иностранного. Я сам не имею никакого преподавательского опыта или соответствующего образования, могу лишь помогать студентам как носитель языка. Существуют ли учебные пособия по русскому как иностранному для начинающих, рассчитанные на изучение в коммуникативном стиле? Я сам изучал немецкий как иностранный в Гёте-институте по учебникам Optimal и Schritte, которые как раз предполагают такой способ изучения языка, и мне он показался очень эффективным.

Насколько велика роль преподавателя в изучении языка? Какие бы вы дали рекомендации или посоветовали методики? Наверняка ведь всё это существует. Очевидно, что на начальных уровнях это весьма важно. Хотелось бы также услышать мнения студентов, изучающих русский как иностранный. Что помогает вам в изучении языка на разных уровнях? Что бы вы хотели делать больше, что меньше?

Как мне кажется, цель всего мероприятия на текущий момент -- оценить интерес студентов к русскому языку и посмотреть, будет ли прогресс и дальнейший интерес через месяц-другой занятий, при условии, что "нормального" преподавателя нет, но есть помощь в виде носителя языка. Речь идёт о немецкоязычных студентах в возрасте 20-26 с первым иностранным английским.

Comment: этот вопрос виден в списке вопросов на [russian.se], но когда пользователь нажимает на него, то попадает в [meta.russian.se].

Comment: @user244413 Так и задумано. Обсуждения и дискуссии происходят на Мете, а не на основном сайте.

Comment: @artemix, а то, что на Мете у вопроса есть 2 голоса, а на основном сайте 0, это тоже так задумано? А зачем?

Comment: @user244413: в этом суть миграции вопроса с того раздела StackExchange, в котором он был оффтопиком.

Comment: @user244413 Кроме того голоса на основном сайте это + к рейтингу, а на этом сайте голоса на рейтинг не влияют - это просто согласие/несогласие с поднятым вопросом. На основном сайте мигрированный вопрос через некоторое время автоматически удалится вообще.

Comment: I realize this question is old now, but I'm just leaving a reminder for people who come across it in the future: please keep all posts on meta in English, so the Community Managers at SE (like me) can keep up to date on what's going on. It's fine to write in Russian, as long as the English is there too, the way the [community FAQ](http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/251/russian-se-community-faq) does it.

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению обычные школьные учебники русского языка не годятся для иностранцев.  Типовое упражнение - "подбери проверочное слово" - не имеет смысла для человека незнакомого с языком.  Я пытался найти пособия для "русского как иностранного" чтобы помочь племяннику, который живёт в смешанной английско-русской семье и очень слабо владеет русским. Учебники такого типа есть, но то что я видел было либо слишком просто, либо сложно для него.  Мне не попалась ни одна серия книг с чётко выстроенной учебной программой от азов к более сложным выражениям и предложениям.

В описанных вами условиях я бы ориентировался на пособия для самостоятельного (полностью автономного) изучения языка. Я самостоятельно изучил французский и испанский (в школе учил английский).  От полного нуля, до возможности читать технические и бюрократические документы.  При изучении я пользовался курсом Pimsleur. 90 уроков этого курса помогают изучить язык от нуля до чуть ниже уровня A1 (по классификации Common European Framework / Gemeinsamer Europäischer Referenzrahmen).  У них также есть курс для изучающих русский язык. Лично мне этот метод кажется очень эффективным. Подробная критика (за и против) курса Pimsleur есть на интернете. Pimsleur это исключительно аудио-курс, предполагающий знание английского языка, т.к. ведущий говорит на английском.  Встречавшиеся мне школьники в Берлине свободно болтали по английски, так что это может быть не проблема. Оффициальная копия курса стоит дорого, это может быть более существенной проблемой.

Аудио-курс можно дополнить изучением алфавита и основ чтения.  Читать, мне кажется, уже лучше учиться когда студенты умеют немножко говорить: базовые выражения, стандартные ситуации и т.п. Алфавит можно выучить на memrise.com Потом поупражняться в основах чтения у того же Pimsleur-a.